# Reduce the number of distinct elements in array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of numbers and another number `K`.

My task is to reduce the number of distinct elements in the array. For that, I can update the array several times. For updating the array, I have to follow these steps:

Select an element at index `i` and add that element by `K`, and reduce all other remaining elements by `K`.

For updating an array I can select the same index several times.

Example:

```
K = 1
Array: [3,1,3]    
Answer: 3
```

I am picking index = 1, as [3-1, 1+1, 3-1] = [2,2,2] so we have number 2 that appears 3 times so this element occurs maximum number of times. So answer is 3.

Another example:

```
K = 1
Array: [1,2,2]
Answer: 2
```

It's not possible to make all elements same, so we have number 2 that appears 2 times, so answer is 2.

Array size can be [1, 1000], and the value of K and elements in array is in range [0, 1000]

Here is my code that I tried, my my approach is not correct.

```
public static int process(int K, int[] A) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
        for (int key : A) {
            map.put(key, map.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);
        }
        int result = 0;
        boolean flag = false;
        int last = -1, cur = -1;
        for (int key : map.keySet()) {
            if (flag == false) {
                flag = true;
                last = key;
                continue;
            }
            cur = key;
            int a = map.get(last), b = map.get(cur);
            if (Math.abs(last - cur) > K) {
                result += a + b;
            } else {
                result += Math.max(a, b);
            }
        }
        last = cur;

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Okay, so what code have you started writing already to turn your own reasoning into something a computer can perform, and where in that code do things stop working as expected, and what have you already tried to search/debug to try to understand why it's not doing what you thought it should be doing?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I started with a treemap with key as the number and value as its frequency, then I am checking the adjacent keys , if they differ by K, I am adding the frequency to result, otherwise I am getting the maximum frequency for those keys. I solved the my sample test case which I posted but I see I am doing a wrong approach.

Comment: So wait, you need the sum of elements stay the same but the number of distinct values should be reduced? Wouldn't filling the whole array with `0`s work and the last element equals the sum? :)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I want to reduce the number of uniques as per my task.

Comment: Can you show the code you've written so far, and the rational for writing that specific code, [in your post](/help/how-to-ask) though? Remember that questions for more information are never "for the person asking" but always "to make sure the post gets updated so that _everyone_ reading it immediately has all the information needed to help" =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I have added now

Comment: I don't undertand the criteria. What do you mean by *the number of uniques* ? With a final`[2 2 2]` the answer is 3...

Comment: Seems pretty clear? A list `[1,2,3]` has three unique elements, and no duplicates. A list `[2,2,2]` has no unique elements and three duplicates. A list `[1,3,5,5,6,8,12,12,12,12]` has six unique elements, as well as a set of 2 duplicates (5) and a set of 4 duplicates (12).

Comment: @Damien, I want to reduce the distinct numbers in the array and make them same as much as possible. so for [2,2,2] we are 3 items that are same and maximum. so answer is 3. Lets say if after updating the array becomes [2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,6,6,6] (just assuming no furthe updates not possible) my answer will be 5 as the number four appears 5 times which is maximum.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, is there any problem the way i framed the question? should i add more details for clarity? please let me know

Answer (score 3):

When looking at the examples with `K = 1`, it is clear that the answer
depends on the parity of the elements. Only elements with same parity can be set to the same level,
and all elements with same parity can be joined.

For example:

```
[2 4 6] -> [1 5 5] -> [2 4 4] -> [3 3 3]
[1 2 2] -> [2 1 1] ... no progress
```

With `K = 1`, we have to consider value modulo 2, i.e. modulo `2*K`.
When `K` is different of one, for example `K = 2`, two numbers can be joined only there are separated by a distance multiple of 4, i.e. of `2*K`.

```
[2 6 6] -> [4 4 4]
```

For K different from 1, instead of creating buckets for numbers with same parity,
we just create buckets according to value modulo 2K.
We just have to pay attention to use the modulo and not the remainder, the values are different for negative values.

Then the answer if simply the highest size of a bucket.

*Output:*

```
K = 1  Array : 3 1 3            -> 3
K = 1  Array : 1 2 2            -> 2
K = 1  Array : 2 3 4 7 4 9 11   -> 4
K = 1  Array : -3 -1 2 3        -> 3
K = 3  Array : -7 -1 0 1 2 4 5  -> 3
```

Here is a simple code in C++ to illustrate the algorithm.

In this code, the value `val_modulo` modulo 2K of each element is calculated.
Then, the orresponding counter is increased

```
Bucket[val_modulo] = Bucket[val_modulo] + 1
```

At the end, the highest value corresponds to the number of repetitions of the most repeated final value.

We may note that the number of non empty bucket corrresponds to the number of different
final values (not used in this code).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

void print (const std::vector<int> &A, const std::string &after = "\n", const std::string &before = "") {
    std::cout << before;
    for (int x: A) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << after;
}

int Modulo (int n, int mod) {
    int ans = n % mod;
    if (ans < 0) ans += mod;
    return ans;
}

int max_equal(int K, std::vector<int> A) {
    K = std::abs(K);    // useful befoe taking the modulo
    std::map<int, int> Buckets;
    int nmax = 0;
    int mod = 2*K;
    for (int x: A) {
        
        int val_modulo = Modulo (x, mod);       // and not x*mod, as x can be negative
        Buckets[val_modulo]++;
    }
    for (auto x: Buckets) {
        if (x.second > nmax) {
            nmax = x.second;
        }
    }
    return nmax;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> examples = {
        {3, 1, 3},
        {1, 2, 2},
        {2, 3, 4, 7, 4, 9, 11},
        {-3, -1, 2, 3},
        {-7, -1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5}
        
    };
    std::vector<int> tab_K = {1, 1, 1, 1, 3};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < examples.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "K = " << tab_K[i] << "  Array : ";
        print (examples[i], " -> ");
        auto ans = max_equal (tab_K[i], examples[i]);
        std::cout << ans << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you please explain more on how this program solves the task, I am not able to understand clearly.

Comment: What do you have difficulty to understand? What the code is effectively doing, or why is it supposed to provide the  good result?

Comment: `What the code is effectively doing, or why is it supposed to provide the good result?` Yes both I did not understand

Comment: I tried to provide more explanations in the post.

Comment: `With K = 1, we have to consider value modulo 2, i.e. modulo 2*K.
When K is different of one, for example K = 2, two numbers can be joined only there are separated by a distance multiple of 4, i.e. of 2*K.` Can you please explain more on this? how this modulo thing solves this problem. Also I did not understand this statement - `Only elements with same parity can be set to the same level, and all elements with same parity can be joined.`

Comment: Two numbers are separated by  a distance multiple of 2K if and only if they have the same value modulo 2K. Concerning the 2nd pont, I just mean that values will be merged with same value at the end if and only if there are initially separated by a multiple of 2, i.e. if they have the same value modulo 2. Maybe you are not familiar with this notion *modulo*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is conceptual, and translating it in somewhat computing code.

Let's look:

We pick a number (by index, which is irrelevant), and for all the occurrences we add *K*. All others we subtract *K* And then the number of same occurrences must be maximal.

The same occurrences can only grow when the picked number + *K* is equal to another number - *K*.

***The data structure:***

A map with the array numbers as key, and mapped to *frequency* (how often the number occurs in the array).

So:

> pickedNumber.value + *K* = otherNumber.value - *K*
>
> =>  otherNumber.value = pickedNumber.value + 2**K*

Note that as there is only one single otherNumber, derived from the pickedNumber.
(It might occur more than once.)

And we want maximal:

```
pickedNumber.frequency + otherNumber.frequency maximal.
```

Though map is not really needed, a sorted array would do too, let's do a map:

***The algorithm:***

*Kept simple.*

```
    int[] numbers = {3, 1, 3};
    int index = pickedIndexOfBestSolution(numbers, 1);
    System.out.println("Index: " + index);

int pickedIndexOfBestSolution(int[] numbers, int k) {
    Map<Integer, Long> frequencyTable = IntStream.of(numbers)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                     Collectors.counting()));
    int bestNumber = frequencyTable.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(e -> -e.getValue()
                    - frequencyTable.getOrDefault(e.getKey() + 2*k, 0L)))
            .findFirst()
            .map(e -> e.getKey())
            .orElseThrow();
    int index = -1;
    while (numbers[++index] != bestNumber) {
    }
    return index;
}
```

The frequency table I filled using an `IntStream` and `groupingBy` (just as SQL).
As `counting` is done with `long`, I just kept that.

To find the max I counted the new occurrence count trying to add the "other" number's frequency too; 0 when no other number.
Instead of using `.reverse()` to reverse the comparison (largest, max, first), I took the negative value, which to me seems more calculatory.
Notice that a Stream with findFirst to find the max is probably optimal too: no need that the stream creates an intermediate list.

For the index I used brute force (*while* loop), a kind of `indexOf`.

Notice if there is no other number, it returns the index of a number with the most occurrences. Which is fine.

***In short:***

You see the different approach. Actually simpler, and more solid. In fact applying
some (minor) intelligence first. Trying to nail down the problem first.

Comment: `We pick a number (by index, which is irrelevant), and for all the occurrences we add K.` In my problem, I have to select an index and increment that element by K , and all other elements should be reduced by k. So ` for all the occurrences we add K` statement is contradicting for my requirement.

Comment: I thought if at that index there a 3, then all 3s are incremented. Hence you could pick any index of the 3s.

Comment: As per my requirement, only a single element is incremented by K, all remaining elements are reduced by K. So even if 3 is repeated multiple times, only a single item is incremented.

Comment: It would still work, the new count being 1 + otherNumber.frequency. I find that an odd problem, just a better solution by 1? Are you sure your interpretation of the problem is correct? I would rather expect 5 occurrences of 1 and 4 of 3 giving 9 occurrences, and the result any index of 3.

Comment: (No problem at my side. You know best.) Single element, not single number value.